# Making singular nouns plural in C

Tags: c, c-strings

I have created this function to make singular nouns plural in c.

```
void pluralize()
{
char noun[SIZE];

printf("Please input a noun: ");
fgets(noun, SIZE, stdin);

int length = strlen(noun);

if (noun[length-1] == 'y')
{
    noun[(strlen(noun))-1] = 'i';
    noun[(strlen(noun))] = 'e';
    noun[(strlen(noun) + 1)] = 's';
    noun[(strlen(noun) + 2)] = '\0';
}

printf("The plural of your word is: %s", noun);
}
```

I have only done the y->ies case, but when I input the word "diary" it gives me back the same word. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `noun[(strlen(noun))] = 'e';` When you do that you overwrite the original NUL character which means `noun` is no longer a string and all the `strlen` calls after that result in Undefined Behaviour. Use `length` instead of `strlen`;

Comment: Adding a line like `printf("you typed: [%s]\n", noun);` just below the `fgets()` call will let you examine the string you are attempting to modify... in particular, it will make it apparent in the output that the string has a newline character at the end, which is why your `if (noun[length-1] == 'y')` test doesn't pass.

Comment: This is hard because some words don't have plurals (like "sheep") and some need an "es" (like "church" and "veto" - but not "photo") and some have completely different words (like "goose" and "mouse") and you can't use heuristics because "mouse" and "house" don't pluralize the same way (and there are others like "goose" and "moose") and what about "man"?  And don't forget ones ending in "fe" like "knife"

Comment: `noun[length-1] == 'y'` not likely.  `noun[length-1] == '\n'` is _very likely_.  Post `SIZE` and input used.